# APPIUM Android: Implicit wait and explicit wait are not working

Tags: appium, appium-android

Implicit and explicit waits are not working when automating the native app. `driver` does not wait for the element to visible. Have already set the implicit wait of 25 seconds and also explicit wait`(visibilityOf(element))` is defined before performing any action with the element.

The exception is coming as:

> Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {stacktrace=NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

`driver` does not wait for the element to be visible when the navigating to the next screen and straight away throws the above exception.

**NOTE**: Code works fine when `Thread.sleep()` wait is used. But fails when `Thread.sleep()` is not used.

Have tried the following ways:

1. Defined the implicit wait and pageLoadTimeout after Android driver is 
   initialized with required desired capabilities and URL.
2. Defined implicit wait and pageLoadTimeout in the `@BeforeTest` method in the 
   TestNG test class.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

You have NOT to set both waits. If you want to let your driver waits for the element to be visible, use this code during driver initialization:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```